# Prevent vuetify side navigation drawer to overlap with pages content

Tags: responsive-design, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, navigation-drawer, sidebar

I'm trying to prevent the vuetify `v-navigation-drawer` to overlap with the pages content.

How can I center the `v-main` content in a responsive way ?

https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxt-vuetify-sidenav-u0xte?file=/layouts/default.vue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is documented behavior. https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/navigation-drawers/#caveats

```
The expand-on-hover prop does not alter the content area of v-main. To have content area respond to expand-on-hover, bind mini-variant.sync to a data prop.
```

so all you need to do is create a data variable and bind it to the mini-variant.sync

```html
<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer app absolute mini-variant expand-on-hover left :mini-variant.sync="mini">
  </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "SideNav",
  data() {
    return {
        mini: true
    }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are looking for is the `app` property of the navigation component.

Juste remove it, and you will have the expected result

```
<v-navigation-drawer
    permanent
    mini-variant
    expand-on-hover
    left
>
```

And btw, why did you bind `value` to *true* ? There is no reason to do this :p You can remove it

EDIT :
Sorry, i forgot that in my case, i have a parent container that enclose `v-navigation-drawer` and `v-main`

```
<v-container
      fluid
      class="d-flex flex-row align-start pa-0 align-stretch"
    >
        <v-navigation-drawer
            permanent
            mini-variant
            expand-on-hover
            left
        >
        </v-navigation-drawer>
        <v-main></v-main>
    </v-container>
```

Comment: I tried to remove the `app` property but it doesn't seems to have the desired effect. I updated the [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxt-vuetify-sidenav-u0xte?file=/components/SideNav.vue) so you can see what's happening. Also I was using the `value` binding with a vuex state mapping and I forgot `true` was its default value ^^"

Comment: Oh sorry, i didn't see that in my case, i have a parent container, i've updated my code above

Comment: Thank you a lot ! It first worked in my example. But when I added it in my project, the content of my `v-main` pages interfered and the drawer is no longer showing. I found this was due to a simple [`v-card` component](https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxt-vuetify-sidenav-u0xte?file=/components/MainCard.vue). Could you explain what I doing wrong ? Also, before adding the parent container, I found that removing the `app` property causes the drawer to appear under the `v-app-bar`. Shoud I also remove the `app` property from my top bar component ?